# How to build complex scopes in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm a bit new to Mongoid and I'm trying to build a kind of complex scope in my model. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
scope :for_currency, ->(currency){ where(price.currency.iso_code: currency.iso_code) }
```

The model I want this scope for, named **PaymentTerm**, has a *has_one* relationship to a **Price** model, which *belongs_to* a **Currency** model. And as you can see I'm trying to get the **PaymentTerms** where its **Price** has a **Currency** *ISO* coded with the value I'm passing as a parameter to the block.

Does anyone knows a great and valid approach to achieve this?. Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you should define a method to solve it

```
def self.for_currency(currency)
  self.all.select {|pt| pt.currency.iso_code == currency.iso_code }
end
```

it will return a array result but not a mongoid::Criteria. And I suggest that if this scope used frequently, create a new field in `PaymentTerm` model to save this code like `field :currency_iso_code`, then

```
scope :for_currency, ->(currency){ where(currency_iso_code: currency.iso_code) }
```

redundant data will make more faster speed.

Comment: I'll give it a try defining a method as you say. And I'll consider your advice about redundancy. I really appreciate your answer!!!. Best,

Comment: I'd like to ask you one more thing dddd1919. This method returns an array of the selected results. Is there a way to return a Mongoid Criteria so that I can be able to chain it as if it were a scope?

Comment: Once I met this question that select data by crossing table but could not find a way to get a mongoid::Criteria instance. If you want to make some filter with that array result, you can go on using `select` method. But if data size giant, suggest using second plan.